# Scaladoc class member visibility

Tags: scala, enumeration

When checking the scaladoc to see documentation for the Value(x: String) function, I noticed it was missing - http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration

However it is there in the source code -

```
protected final def Value(name: String): Value = Value(nextId, name)
```

Does the scaladoc only show public members then ? If so, how is one supposed to know the full range of inheritable functionality?

Comment: Click on "Visibility: All", and it will be shown

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the mickey mouse quesiton - just my first time looking at these docs...